# How can I use Python 2.6 in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pydev

The default version of Python on Ubuntu 11.10 is 2.7, but I'm looking for 2.6. How do I make it default and where is the executable located?

I type `which python2.6` but it returns nothing, yet I did have a python2.6 folder under `/usr/lib/python2.6`. But it doesn't look like the python2.7 which is at the same path `/usr/lib/`. Inside the python2.6, there are two folders: `dist-packages` and `lib-dynload`.

Actually I am configuring PyDev, and it requires me to specify where the python2.6 executable is. The python2.7 executable has been easily located by just using auto configuration as it is the default.

Comment: As far as making a certain version of python the default (when multiple are installed) the *Ubuntu/Debian* way would be to use the `/etc/alternatives` system.  Check this out: http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/update-alternatives-in-debian/.  Someone should file a bug with Ubuntu that their python packages don't already do this.

Comment: For 12.04, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/125342/how-can-i-install-python-2-6-on-12-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the package `python2.6` (`apt-get install python2.6`). At this point, the default version of Python will still be 2.7. You can change this via

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Note that there's a decent chance this could cause problems with your system. Several scripts assume the default version of Python is 2.7 and may break when run under a different version. If you have a script that explicitly requires Python 2.6, you can add a shebang at the beginning of your script to specify the version

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make it be more specific, would you please take a look at see if you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: So just install the `python2.6` package: `sudo apt-get install python2.6`.

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting one of these answers if it solved your problem. This will make it more likely that people will help you in the future.

Answer (score 4):

On many systems, one version of python is the default.  The rest get called by their name and version number:

```
~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.2
~ $ python2.6 --version
Python 2.6.7
```

Per the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#Python), these should be available in Oneiric.

Your other questions:

- Where is it?   Run `$ which python2.6` to find out.
- How to make it the default?   The safest way is to use *alias* so that change will be only visible to you.  Otherwise, if you repoint /usr/bin/python to an unexpected version of Python, you will may break the OS scripts that rely on Python2.7.  Rather than changing the default, it is better to just call the specific version of Python you need.

Comment: I type `which python2.6` but it returns nothing, yet I did have a `python2.6` folder under `/usr/lib/python2.6`. But it doesn't look like the python2.7 which is at the same path `/usr/lib/`. Inside the python2.6, there are two folders: `dist-packages` and `lib-dynload`. Actually I am configuring the PyDev, and it requires me to specific where is the python2.6 executable.  Would you please give me some advise on how can I make this python2.6 useful? Thank you so much!!

Comment: if which returns nothing, try reinstalling the package. usually ubuntu creates a symlink /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/pythonx. I have both installed and they're in /usr/bin

Comment: @Kevin I would say that it's not installed, at least by `apt`.  If it were it would exist at `/usr/bin/python2.6` like everyone else said.